# How to get data from axios to a div

Tags: vue.js, axios

This configuration is extremely unstable. In different browsers, it may work once, or not display data at all.

**axiosDate.php**

```
<?php
     $today = date("d.m.Y, H:i");
     echo $today;
?>
```

**component.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="info" id="date">date</div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

mounted() {
axios.get('/axiosDate.php')
    .then(respond => {
 document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = respond.data; 
  }),
}
</script>
```

tell me how to put the data in the div "date"?

Comment: you should probably read the official vue documentation first. it does not take too long and it is really well written. accessing the DOM directly is something you want to avoid in most modern frontend frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this, declare a v-model `date`, and change the value of the model

```
<template>
    <div>{{date}}</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  mounted() {
    axios.get('/axiosDate.php')
      .then(respond => {
        this.date = respond.data
    }),
  },
  data(){
    return {
        date:''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you should update your awnser to have a default export I think. this is no valid js.